# Why are python Generic classes not enforcing their refined types?

Tags: python

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    def my_func_add(cls, a: T, b: T) -> T:
        return a+b
        
print(MyClass[int].my_func_add("1","2"))
```

The output of the above is "12", without any error. I assume `MyClass[int]`  means `T` must be an int, why does it allow string inputs and outputs? What's the point of generics then?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to throw an error? MyPy, for example, _does_: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=788f31a5ee80224505a37bddcafb795d. [_"The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: it should raise TypeError: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59589910/13285707

Comment: I am not talking about type checks, but actual runtime errors, because it says we are returning ```int``` (via type refinement) but we are actually returning ```str``` in this case. Isn't that the whole point of generics?

Comment: Then it's unclear why you expected an error. The Python runtime **does not** enforce anything based on the type metadata, you'll only get runtime errors for types that are actually incompatible (e.g. `MyClass.my_func_add("1", 2)`).

Comment: [quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) → `Note The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.`

Comment: *"I assume MyClass[int] means T must be an int"* - no, in Python type enforcement does not exist. Those are merely *hints* for the programmer using the function.

Comment: Dupe: [Possible to enforce type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838471/possible-to-enforce-type-hints) and also maybe [Python Type Hinting: How do I enforce that project wide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944201/python-type-hinting-how-do-i-enforce-that-project-wide)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli @rzlvmp @jonrsharpe thanks, but how come I am even allowed to do ```MyClass.my_func_add("1","2")```, without any type refinement specified to ```MyClass``` such as ```MyClass[int]``` ? Is that legal in python too?

Comment: @user1008636 yes, completely lega. You can also do `MyClass.my_func_add([1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6])` for what it's worth. Again, Python does not care about type hints at runtime. If two variables support addition, they will add together.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli thanks, then why is it necessary to define ```class MyClass(Generic[T])```, why can't we just do ```class MyClass``` and only use ```T``` on the function parameters ?

Comment: @user1008636 how would you use `T` on the function parameters meaningfully without first binding it to any type? `T` alone is merely a placeholder, it does not define an actual type. That's why you need to subclass `Generic[T]`. If you just want to support `int` then avoid all of this altogether and do `def my_func_add(cls, a: int, b: int) -> int: ...`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli what use case would not be supported without subclassing Generic[T] ?